# SQLite equivalent query of the given MSSQL query.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, database-partitioning, row-number

I've been trying to find a way to use the row_number over partition by, but couldn't find how to do so in SQLite.
I'm trying to convert the following ***the working query from MSSQL syntax to SQLite:***

```
    select TKG, hour, CAP, switch, Calls
from 
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by TKG order by cap desc) rn
  from yourtable 
) t1
where rn = 1
```

Here's an example with SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bf9a/3

Basically, I have the following table:

```
TKG   hour  CAP SWITCH  CALLS
AAA   7     45  HH      56
AAA   8     35  HH      76
AAA   9     25  HH      43
BBB   7     32  LL      5
BBB   8     43  LL      65
BBB   9     434 LL      65
CCC   7     54  JJ      43
CCC   8     564 JJ      43
CCC   9     54  JJ      65
ddd   7     10  MM      4
ddd   8     10  MM      3
ddd   9     10  MM      5
```

I need to order by the TKG with the max CAP so the output will look like this:

```
TKG hour    CAP SWITCH  CALLS
AAA 7       45  HH      56
BBB 9       434 LL      65
CCC 8       564 JJ      43
ddd 7       10  MM      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing unique key it's really hard to do in readable way (no `cross apply`, no windowed functions). If you can afford to add id into your table, you can do:

```
select *
from yourtable
where
    id in (
        select min(y.id)
        from yourtable as y
            inner join (
            select [TKG], max([CAP]) as [CAP]
            from yourtable
            group by [TKG]
        ) as y2 on y2.[TKG] = y.[TKG] and y2.[CAP] = y.[CAP]
        group by y.[TKG]
    )
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6d5e9/2)

Considering myself lucky that I don't work in SQLite often :)

Comment: BTW, I'm trying to get the result set in descending order. I tried to put "order by y.id desc" after the group by y.[TKG] but that won't work. Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: do you want the final result set ordered descending? by which columns